# How to invoke/execute Control C (SIGINT) using code inside the while loop of a java program

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Suppose I have the following run() method:

```
  public void run()
  {

    String responseLine = "";
    responseCount = 0;
    try 
    {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null)
      {
          if(responseLine!=null && !responseLine.equals(null) && responseLine!="null" && !responseLine.equals("null") && !responseLine.contains("null"))
         {

              System.out.println(responseLine);
              responseCount = responseCount + 1;
         }

         else if(responseLine.contains("null") || responseLine.equals("null") || responseLine==null || responseLine.equals(null) || responseLine.isEmpty() == true)
         {
         }


      }
      closed = true;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
 }
```

**Notice:** the line that says `while((responseLine = is.readLine())!=null)` is stopped when control D on mac (or control Z on windows) is pressed (null is entered from standard input).

**Goal:** What changes can I make to the code that will instead say `while((responseLine = is.readLine())!=ControlC))`?

**OR**

Let's assume the user presses control D which makes `responseLine` null, what changes could I make to the code inside the while loop to call control C in the console using java code?

Full code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5buwert7ibybof/JavaChatProgram.zip?dl=0

Comment: `System.exit(1);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you, you are correct! post an answer and i'll give you the green checkmark!